# Actionscript littleEndian to c#

Tags: c#, actionscript-3, actionscript, endianness

I inherited a proprietary file parser written in actionscript.  I am converting it to c# and I'm at a loss as to how to handle the following step.

```
public function transform(input:ByteArray) : ByteArray
{
   var output:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
   output.endian = "littleEndian";
   output.writeBytes(input,0,input.length);
   return output;
}
```

I've been trying to read up on endianness, and the only thing I can fathom that this would do is reverse the order of bytes.  Is that correct?  If so, how would I replicate that in c#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code will copy the data in `input` to `output` unmodified (since bytes don't have endianness) and afterwards all read operations from the returned `ByteArray` will use little endian.

On little endian platforms (x86 for example and nowadays pretty much all OSes ARMs as far as I know) .NET will by default use little endian if you use `BinaryReader` for example.

So basically that code in .NET would be to create a `MemoryStream` of the bytes and then a `BinaryReader` for that stream.

You can check whether the platform on which your C# code is running on is little or big endian by using [`BitConverter.IsLittleEndian`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.islittleendian(v=vs.110).aspx)